# SQL Server 2008 SSRS Home page error

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I created a basic report in BI using Report Wizard and tried to publish it.

This is the error I get -

> Error 1   The permissions granted to user 'xx-PC\xx' are insufficient
>   for performing this operation.        0   0

On the URL ../Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx I get this error

> User 'xx-PC\xx' does not have required permissions. Verify that
>   sufficient permissions     have been granted and Windows User Account
>   Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For this issue you need to add your account into ReportServer directory. Please follow following steps to solve this issue -

- Go to the report server url (localhost/Reports)
- Click on '**Folder Settings**' button
- Click on '**New Role Asignment**'
- Add your '**Group or user name**' (Domain name with ID e.g. ZA\sg677888) and select the all checkbox
- Click Ok

Hope this helps you !!!

Answer (score 0):

I got these error message when browsing the server with NETBIOS name only. Use fully qualified domain name like myreportingserver.mycompany.com